write a power of ten non-integers
I would like to be able to write non-integer powers of 10.
With the siuntix package, I'm tinkering to get something done but it's not very pleasant to read.
How in my example can I write 10^-6.5 properly?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$10^{-6.5}\unit{\mol \per \l}<C_0<\qty{1e-8}{\mol \per \l}$

\end{document}


The siunitx package parses numbers to provides many formatting options (see the manual, section 4.3, Parsing numbers). This can be deactivated with parse-numbers=false, so you can use anything you want. Example, taken from the documentation:
\num[parse-numbers = false]{\sqrt{2}} \\
\qty[parse-numbers = false]{\sqrt{3}}{\metre}

In your case
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

$ \qty[parse-numbers=false]{10^{-6.5}}{\mol \per \l} > C_0 > \qty{e-8}{\mol \per \l} $

\end{document}

would give the desired output.
